# python decode and file writing issue

Tags: python, file, python-2.7, base64, decode

when i try to run this python-2.7 program, it works without any error, but the problem is that it does not convert and write whole file (converts only 98959 line) and original file contains 99157 lines

why it's happening ?

```
import base64
input_file = open("answer.txt","r")
output_file = open("result.txt","w")
for eachline in input_file.readlines():
    output_file.write(base64.b64decode(eachline))
```

original file link: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_566weiakkYLVBhSHJndkFMX3M&authuser=0

thanx in advance if anyone can help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't closed the file

```
output_file.close()
```